# Maya python. parentConstraint by distance

Tags: python, maya

I have two sets of skeletons (A and B), and trying to parent constraint A set of joints to B joints.

What I did was put A selection into A array and B selection to B array.
but how can I proceed parent constraint A to B by distance, which the distance is 0 basically so the toe joint doesn't hook up with fingers.
something like bellow.

I'd appreciate if some one can advise me.

```
firstSel = []
secondSel = []

def firstSelection(*args):

    sel = mc.select(hi = True)
    joints = mc.ls(sl=True, type = "joint")
    firstSel.append(joints)
    print "this is first selection"


def secondSelection(*args):

    tsmgRoot = mc.select(hi = True)
    tsmgJoints = mc.ls(sl=True, type = "joint")
    secondSel.append(tsmgJoints)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35833586/batch-constraining-objects-feathers-to-a-wing

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can constrain objects from one list to another by their world positions. There may be smarter ways of doing it, like adding the values to a `dict` then sorting it, but this feels more readable.

```
import math

# Add code here to get your two selection lists

# Loop through skeleton A
for obj in first_sel:
    closest_jnt = None # Name of the closest joint
    closest_dist = 0 # Distance of the closest joint

    obj_pos = cmds.xform(obj, q=True, ws=True, t=True)

    # Loop through skeleton B to find the nearest joint
    for target in second_sel:
        target_pos = cmds.xform(target, q=True, ws=True, t=True)

        # Calculate the distance between the 2 objects
        dist = math.sqrt((target_pos[0]-obj_pos[0])**2 + 
                         (target_pos[1]-obj_pos[1])**2 + 
                         (target_pos[2]-obj_pos[2])**2)

        # If this is the first object we loop through, automatically say it's the closest
        # Otherwise, check to see if this distance beats the closest distance
        if closest_jnt is None or dist < closest_dist:
            closest_jnt = target
            closest_dist = dist

    cmds.parentConstraint(closest_jnt, obj, mo=True)
```

Also as a side note, no need to do `firstSel.append(joints)` when you're getting your selection (you're actually adding a list to a list!). You can either just assign it directly like `firstSel = mc.ls(sl=True, type = "joint")`, or if the list already exists with some items and you want to add to it, you can use `firstSel.extend(joints)`

Comment: you can also use dist = cmds.distanceDimension( sp=obj_pos, ep=target_pos)

Comment: Yes but this creates a new object that you need to delete later on. It would be faster to do it in memory.